# Keep getting: "stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /target.php on line 30" error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The Error I keep getting is: stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /target.php on line 30

This is my code for this site, I am new to this and i've been trying to do it for over 30 minutes.

I am sorry for asking such a stupid question.

```
<?php

// rnprofile.php
include_once 'rnheader.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
    die("<br /><br />You need to login to view this page");
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
echo "<h3>Edit your Profile</h3>";
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
    $text = sanitizeString($_POST['text']);
    $text = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $text);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM rnprofiles WHERE user='$user'";
    if (queryMysql($query) != false) {
        queryMysql("UPDATE rnprofiles SET text='$text'
            where user='$user'");
    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO rnprofiles VALUES('$user', '$text')";
        queryMysql($query);
    }
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM rnprofiles WHERE user='$user'";

    $result = queryMysql($query);
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $sth->execute();
    if (queryMysql($query) != false/* mysql_num_rows($result) */) {
        $row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $text = stripslashes($row[1]);
    }
    else
        $text = "";
}
$text = stripslashes(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $text));
if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    $saveto = "$user.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $saveto);
    $typeok = TRUE;
    switch ($_FILES['image']['type']) {
        case "image/gif": $src = imagecreatefromgif($saveto);
            break;
        case "image/jpeg": // Both regular and progressive jpegs
        case "image/pjpeg": $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($saveto);
            break;
        case "image/png": $src = imagecreatefrompng($saveto);
            break;
        default: $typeok = FALSE;
            break;
    }
    if ($typeok) {
        list($w, $h) = getimagesize($saveto);
        $max = 100;
        $tw = $w;
        $th = $h;
        if ($w > $h && $max < $w) {
        $th = $max / $w * $h;
        $tw = $max;
    } elseif ($h > $w && $max < $h) {
        $tw = $max / $h * $w;
        $th = $max;
    } elseif ($max < $w) {
        $tw = $th = $max;
    }
    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($tw, $th);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tw, $th, $w, $h);
    imageconvolution($tmp, array(// Sharpen image
        array(−1, −1, −1),
        array(−1, 16, −1),
        array(−1, −1, −1)
            ), 8, 0);
    imagejpeg($tmp, $saveto);
    imagedestroy($tmp);
    imagedestroy($src);
    }
}
showProfile($user);
echo <<<_END
<form method='post' action='rnprofile.php'
enctype='multipart/form-data'>
Enter or edit your details and/or upload an image:<br />
<textarea name='text' cols='40' rows='3'>$text</textarea><br />
Image: <input type='file' name='image' size='14' maxlength='32' />
<input type='submit' value='Save Profile' />
</pre></form>
_END;
?>
```

Comment: well as the error says, its an array not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [PDO::FETCH](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) manual

> **PDO::FETCH_ASSOC**: returns an array indexed by column name as returned
>   in your result set
>
> **PDO::FETCH_NUM**: returns an array indexed by column number as returned
>   in your result set, starting at column 0

you have used  `FETCH_ASSOC` then you must use column name as key of `$row`

```
    $row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $text = stripslashes($row['column_name']);
```

or change it to `FETCH::NUM`

```
 $row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
 $text = stripslashes($row[1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fetchAll` method returns an array containing *all* rows, so this line:

```
$row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

doesn't set `$row` in the way that the name `row` implies. As a result, `$row[1]` is not a single string, but rather, it's an associative array containing an entire row.

You should probably change this:

```
        $row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $text = stripslashes($row[1]);
```

to this:

```
        $rows = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $text = stripslashes($rows[0]['column_name_of_interest']);
```

(Note that I also changed `1` to `0`: arrays are indexed from `0` in PHP, not from `1`.)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using fetchAll, which returns you an array of associative arrays:

```
if (queryMysql($query) != false/* mysql_num_rows($result) */) {
    $row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $text = stripslashes($row[1]);
```

So when you call stripslashes, and pass it `$row[1]`, you're passing it an associative array that's made up of the second result from the database. I think this might do what you mean:

```
if (queryMysql($query) != false/* mysql_num_rows($result) */) {
    if ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
        $text = stripslashes($row[1]);
```

That's assuming that your search for a user by name will only return one result